# Форматирование Текст Файла С++

Tags: c++

Всем Привет . Пытаюсь сделать программу которая отформатирует текст записанный в .txt файле и выведет результат в том же .txt файле с расширением out.

Мучаюсь уже пару дней и пока что смог вот только это додумать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
string line;
int sum=0;
ifstream inData ;
inData.open("input.txt");
ofstream outFile("output.txt");
while(!inData.eof())
{
getline(inData,line);
    int numofChars= line.length();
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n<line.length();n++)
    {
    if (line.at(n) == ' ')
    {
    numofChars--;
    }
    }
sum=numofChars+sum;
}
outFile << sum << endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Смог только сделать чтобы читался текст записанный в начальном файле и посчитать сколько в нем символов но так и не могу додумать как :

1. Вывести вместо числа символов отформатированный текст .
   Попытался вместо

```
outFile << sum << endl
```

использовать

```
outFile << (inData,line) << endl
```

но текст не выводится в файле.

2. Как отформатировать текст по числу символов в каждом ряду , в моем случае нужно чтобы в каждом ряду было 80 символов , то есть начинать текст с нового ряда когда в нем столько символов
   Попробовал :

```
if (sum == 80){
cout << endl;}
```

но тоже не вышло . Есть какая нибудь функция чтобы начинать с нового ряда при определенном количестве символов?

3. Как сделать чтобы ряд не начинался и не заканчивался пробелом? Подумал что надо игнорировать пробел и считывать следующий символ но не уверен .
   Буду благодарен если подскажете как сделать

Comment: `outFile << (inData,line) << endl` - а что вы сдесь вообще пытались сделать? Как это по-вашему впринципе должно работать?

Comment: `while(!inData.eof())` - из раза в раз... Вы там на одном факультете все учитесь что-ли? Нельзя так делать!

Comment: `if (sum == 80){cout << endl;}` - и что эта строка должна нам сказать? вне контекста она вообще ничего не говорит. Если разместить ее в правильном месте, то все будет как вы хотите, а если пихнуть абы куды - то нет. Приводите более развернутые примеры ваших попыток

Comment: К тому же сдесь явно не достаточно информации: если 80-й символ это символ из слова, то что делать? Разбить слово или перенести его на другую строку?

Comment: насчет третьего комментария я так и уточнил в посте " Есть какая нибудь функция чтобы начинать с нового ряда при определенном количестве символов?" если есть такая функция то можно использовать мою строку если она подойдет в данном контексте.

Comment: Да , тут я не уточнил , если 80-й символ в слове то он переносится в следующую строку

Comment: кто "он"? Перечитайте ваш коммент и поясните что вы имели ввиду

Comment: "он" - символ вместе со словом в котором он состоит

Comment: в таком случае будет немного сложнее: вам нужно считать текст, разбить его по словам и дальше уже итерироваться по словам и проверять расположение последнего символа. Если он выходит за 80-й столбец, то слово - в новую строку, а счетчик символов обнуляется и начинаете считать заново. Короче, ничего сверх сложного.

Comment: а как собственно сделать этот счётчик ? К сожалению , за свою недолгое обучение еще не доводилось иметь дело с интегрированием по словам , ну и собственно с такого рода счетчиками

Comment: Счетчик - всмысле переменная. Просто считаете количество символов и ложите его в эту переменную

Comment: Я это понял но вот как это реализовать не имею понятия

Comment: что конкретно вам не понятно?

Comment: как можно считывать из текст файла слова и интегрировать их в эту переменную ? как проверять расположение последнего символа?

Comment: просто считайте весь ваш файл в строку и дальше работайте с ней как со строкой. Вряд ли файл у вас будет столь большим, что его нельзя будет загрузить в оперативку целиком